# SQL Server Distinct Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to come up with a way that I can get only 16 rows (Which is 16 distinct records based on SERV_ACCT) with only the recent ACCOUNT. I am using Distinct and group by and I thought this would solve the problem, but I keep getting 20 rows.

DECLARE

```
 @CustomerID int = 8,
 @UtilityCompanyID int = 1


    SELECT DISTINCT SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT, MAX(INV_DATE)
    FROM tblAPSData

    WHERE SERV_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT ServiceAccount
                FROM tblMEP_Meters
                JOIN tblMEP_Sites
                ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

                JOIN tblMEP_Projects
                ON tblMEP_Projects.ID = tblMEP_Sites.ProjectID

                WHERE CustomerID = 8
                AND Type = 1
                )

    AND ACCOUNT IN (SELECT AccountNumber
                    FROM tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
                    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
                    AND UtilityCompanyID = @UtilityCompanyID)

    AND INV_DATE > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
    GROUP BY SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT
    ORDER BY SERV_ACCT
```

the result is the following:

```
SERV_ACCT   ACCOUNT (No column name)
0289S61288  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
0492S90281  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
0492S90281  651412281   2013-04-08 00:00:00.000
1303S90280  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
1435S01282  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
1440S13289  312937281   2013-06-24 00:00:00.000
1548S00286  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
1548S00286  308710287   2013-04-08 00:00:00.000
2498S21288  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
5384S92284  979437282   2013-06-24 00:00:00.000
5538S21284  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
6109S12286  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
7358S00281  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
7358S00281  659710281   2013-04-08 00:00:00.000
7488S22289  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
8058S12287  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
9058S00288  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
9168S00282  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
9168S00282  570810282   2013-04-08 00:00:00.000
9645S21281  117512280   2013-06-12 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Since you are grouping by `SERV_ACCT` and `ACCOUNT` you will return all `DISTINCT` combinations of those two fields, you need to decide which values you want to return, you can use MAX/MIN if it's by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would combine your where clause statements into JOINs for better performance. Then use a partitioning function to rank your rows by date.

[RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
aps.SERV_ACCT
, aps.ACCOUNT
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aps.SERV_ACCT ORDER BY aps.INV_DATE DESC) [row]
    FROM tblAPSData aps
    INNER JOIN tblMEP_Meters mep
      ON aps.SERV_ACCT = mep.ServiceAccount
    INNER JOIN tblMEP_Sites site
      ON site.SiteID = mep.ID
    INNER JOIN tbl_MEP_Projects proj
      ON proj.ID = site.ProjectID
      AND proj.CustomerID = 8 -- Move this to appropriate table
      AND proj.Type = 1 --Move this to appropriate table assumed it was on proj
    INNER JOIN tblMEP_CustomerAccounts custAcc
      ON custAcc.AccountNumber = aps.Account
      AND custAcc.CustomerID = @CustomerID
      AND custAcc.UtilityCompanyID = @UtilityCompanyID
WHERE aps.INV_DATE > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
) data
WHERE
  data.row = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using at least SQL-Server 2005 you can use ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER` in a cte:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT [SERV_ACCT], [ACCOUNT], [INV_DATE],
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SERV_ACCT ORDER BY INV_DATE DESC)
  FROM dbo.Table1
)
SELECT [SERV_ACCT], [ACCOUNT], [INV_DATE]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c5f7/1/0)

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [WITH common_table_expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: For my code, where do you add that piece of code? I am really not sure. Thank you.

Comment: You can add your complete query to the cte which is similar to a sub query. The important part is the row_number with the partition by which returns One for the latest record of each Serv_Acct.